# How to know when all data has arrived in node sockets

Tags: flash, node.js, sockets, actionscript

I'm using node.js with the net module on my backend and flash on my frontend. I want to pass objects with json format. How would I know when all data has arrived in my backend so I can then do a JSON.parse?

My actionscript:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.msg = "I want pizza";
xmlSocket.send(JSON.encode(obj));
```

My javascript:

```
    socket.on("data", function(data){
        var msg = JSON.parse(data.toString());

        var i = 0;
        while(i < clientData.length){

            var client = clientData[i];
            if(client.writable){
                client.write(msg.msg, 'utf8');
            }
            i++;    
        }

});
```

At the moment I'm getting an error, which I'm not sure has to do with this since it displays the whole object:

```
undefined:1
{"msg":"I want pizza"}
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know when the data has ended, you have to add something in front that specifies the length or something at the end that shows that the data is over. So, either put the length in front of the JSON or put a newline after each JSON object.

Also: What's `JSON.encode`? I only know `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Could you show me an example of how you would do the check in javascript? Thanks. JSON.encode is actionscript not javascript. It's from com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.

Comment: @Bastrix: For the appended-newline method: First read a string from the socket and append it to the data, then, as long as the data contains newlines, take the string from the beginning to the first newline, remove it from the original string and interpret it as JSON. E.g. `var data_buffer=''; socket.on('data', function(data) {data_buffer+=data; var i; while ((i = data_buffer.indexOf('\n')) != -1) {do_stuff_with(JSON.parse(data_buffer.substring(0, i)));data_buffer=data_buffer.substring(i+1);}})`

Comment: Thank you! it works. I'm a bit confused with your last line of code though. This is thought to work with several json objects separated by \n... right? So it would work with one single object as well as something like { "msg": "peanut" }\n{ "msg": "butter" }\n ... correct?

Comment: In order for me to be able to send several objects with your example, I tweaked just a couple of things. Since the character \ is an escape character. I check for: while ((i = data_buffer.indexOf('\\n')).... Also, in the last line, to skip ahead of the new line I add 2 positions insead of one: data_buffer=data_buffer.substring(i+2);... This seems to work on my local network with small objects. I haven't tested on a remote server with large objects yet. :)

Comment: @Bastrix: Uh, I think you're doing it wrong. You really want to use the newline character, not the string \n, as seperator because a real newline can't appear inside JSON, but \n can. You want a seperator that can't appear inside regular data.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'm using the actual character now, not a string. Seems to work even when sending objects inside my game loop to sync with server. Thanks again thejh.